# Is there a way to display % codes as literal characters in the browser’s URL bar?

Tags: browser, url

Some websites use % codes (e.g., `%3A`) in their URLs. This makes the URL quite unreadable. I understand why these characters need to be escaped, but from a user perspective, it would sometimes be better if I could just see the literal characters directly. Of course, there would need to be some other method to indicate that the characters are escaped. A special color could do it (see my screenshot).

Of course, when copy-pasting such an URL, the URL would still contain the % codes, not the literal characters, so nothing would change there. This feature would be purely visual, in the URL bar.

Does anything like this exist?

[image]

Comment: You should look for a browser extention that can urlencode /decode. Something like this https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/urlencoder/knemomiohalcaaafakbiiijddjdhcnhe?hl=en or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37348828/decode-url-via-chrome-extension/37349317

Comment: @Bolli I think you're missing the point

Comment: Don't do that directly in the URL bar, because as you can see in your example that gives you a valid, but completely different URL.

Comment: @gronostaj The value of the URL would not change. It would only be visual, a different way to indicate escaped characters.

Comment: It would change. In the original URL from your example the path consists of three components: `i`, `subscription`, `feed%2Fhttps%3A%2f%2Ftrib.tv%2Ffeed%2F`. The decoded version consists of eight: `i`, `subscription`, `feed`, `https:`, empty string, `trib.tv`, `feed`, empty string. For an HTTP server these are two completely different paths. Try replacing a slash in this page's URL with `%2F` and see if it works (it doesn't)

Comment: I think you're confused because you're missing the important fact that percent encoding is supposed to be used for query parameters, ie. the URL part that comes after `?`. That part _must_ be percent-encoded and the unencoded form is not allowed, so indeed decoding it wouldn't hurt. The path - the part between domain and query parameters - doesn't normally use percent encoding and thus `%` doesn't have any special meaning there. Feedly is cleverly abusing this to ensure slashes in path are not interpreted as directory separators.

Comment: Anyway, I doubt browser extensions are allowed to edit URL bar without navigation, because security implications would be terrifying.